# IEnumerable Return Path

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way of handling the return path For this routine. The Compiler is saying not all paths return a type even though I do inside my switch statement but cause im returning a generic IEnumerable what is my best way of handling the below?.

Any suggestions to how I would handle the query as dont see why I should need to do this three times?.

```
    public IEnumerable<Object> GetMenuItemsFromLevel(ReturnMenuType returnType)
    {
        IEnumerable<menu_top_level> menuTop = from m in db.menu_top_level
                                      where m.top_level_visible =="Yes"                                  
                                              select m;


        IEnumerable<menu_mid_level> menuMid = from m in db.menu_mid_level
                                              where m.mid_level_visible== "Yes"
                                            select m;



        IEnumerable<menu_bot_level> menubottom = from m in db.menu_bot_level
                                              where m.bot_level_visible == "Yes"
                                              select m;

        // Switch on the Priority enum.
        switch (returnType)
        {
            case ReturnMenuType.TopLevel:
                return menuTop;
            case ReturnMenuType.MidLevel:
                return menuMid;
            case ReturnMenuType.BottomLevel:
                return menubottom;



        }


    }
```

Comment: this is because your switch statement is based on a enum object. These objects can be null, or more enumerators can be created on the course of time, a default will get your where you want to be

Comment: Consider `GetMenuItemsFromLevel((ReturnMenuType) 255)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather strange that each of your menu objects is of a completely different type (`menu_top_level`, `menu_mid_level`, etc.).  You should try to use polymorphism and extract whatever is common into a common interface, using something like:

```
interface IMenu
{
    // if it's a menu, then it has a 'Visible' property
    bool Visible { get; }
}

class ParentClass
{
    public IEnumerable<IMenu> TopLevelMenu { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IMenu> MidLevelMenu { get; }
    public IEnumerable<IMenu> BottomLevelMenu { get; }
}
```

Getting all visible items is now trivial:

```
public IEnumerable<IMenu> GetVisibleMenus(IEnumerable<IMenu> menu)
{
    return menu.Where(m => m.Visible);
}
```

And you lose those similar LINQ queries altogether:

```
public IEnumerable<IMenu> GetVisibleMenusForLevel(ReturnMenuType returnType)
{
    if (returnType == ReturnMenuType.TopLevel)
        return GetVisibleMenus(db.TopLevelMenu);

    if (returnType == ReturnMenuType.MidLevel)
        return GetVisibleMenus(db.MidLevelMenu);

    // otherwise return the bottom menu
    return GetVisibleMenus(db.BottomLevelMenu);
}
```

Also, the fact that you're using a "type code" (the `ReturnMenuType` in this case) is also a code smell regarding OOP practices. You could make it even simpler by having the parent class store all levels in a single dictionary collection, something like:

```
class ParentClass
{
    private Dictionary<ReturnMenuType, List<IMenu>> _menuItems = InitMenuItems();

    private static Dictionary<ReturnMenuType, List<IMenu>> InitMenuItems()
    {
        return new Dictionary<ReturnMenuType, List<IMenu>>()
        {
            { ReturnMenuType.TopLevel, new List<IMenu>() { some items } },
            { ReturnMenuType.MidLevel, new List<IMenu>() { some items } },
            { ReturnMenuType.BottomLevel, new List<IMenu>() { some items } }
        };
    }

    // getting menu for a level is now as simple as querying the dictionary
    public IEnumerable<IMenu> GetMenusForLevel(ReturnMenuType type)
    {
        return _menuItems[type];
    }
}
```

And your `GetVisibleMenusForLevel` is now even simpler:

```
public IEnumerable<IMenu> GetVisibleMenusForLevel(ReturnMenuType type)
{
    return db.GetMenusForLevel(type).Where(m => m.Visible);
}
```

Finally, ask yourself if you even need the `ReturnMenuType` enum at all. I am pretty certain that you can completely [remove the type code and replace it with polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: what is the purpose of InitMenuItems ?? that was not supplied in code example

Comment: @David: that's supposed to be a method which will fill the dictionary. I can add an example if you want.

Comment: can you add an example

Comment: @David: I've already added the `InitMenuItems()` method to the snippet. It only returns a new dictionary instance filled with items. You might need to adapt the code to your actual use case, I don't know how your app is organized.

Answer (score 3):

Add default at the end of switch:

```
switch (returnType)
    {
        case ReturnMenuType.TopLevel:
            return menuTop;
        case ReturnMenuType.MidLevel:
            return menuMid;
        case ReturnMenuType.BottomLevel:
            return menubottom;

        default:
            return something
```

Comment: Compiler 'smartness' :-)

Answer (score 0):

The switch needs a default. It is possible to enter a value that is NEITHER of the 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

default:
  return new List();

But you should not do it this way anyway.

1. All linq statements are evaluated even you need only one.
2. The returned `IEnumerable` is typed but the method return type is `IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: Actually, LINQ is lazy evaluated, so it shouldn't be a performance issue. But I agree, it's strange to do it this way.

Comment: instead of the return new List(); i would raise an error. this way your program will crash whenever something is there that couldn't/shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Dani please can you suggest a coded answer by editing your answer thanks

Comment: guys im just learning gnerics here so asking the best adivce ;-)

Comment: @DavidBuckley I don't knwo what menu_top_level etc. is, so it's hard to write a good suggestion. I would probably write three specific functions with typed return types instead of calling GetMenuItemsFromLevel.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot return a "default" value, maybe it's best to throw an exception.

```
   // Switch on the Priority enum.
    switch (returnType)
    {
        case ReturnMenuType.TopLevel:
            return menuTop;
        case ReturnMenuType.MidLevel:
            return menuMid;
        case ReturnMenuType.BottomLevel:
            return menubottom;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException(); 
            // throw NotSupportedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

place a default in your constructor

choose based on your preferences to return a NULL or an Exception.

```
switch (returnType)
{
    case ReturnMenuType.TopLevel:
        return menuTop;
    case ReturnMenuType.MidLevel:
        return menuMid;
    case ReturnMenuType.BottomLevel:
        return menubottom;
    default:
        return null;
        //or
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Returntype is not correct.");
}
```

based on your preferences:

if you return NULL:

```
var l = yourobject.GetMenuItemsFromLevel(ReturnMenuType.Unknown);
if(l == null)
return;
```

if you use An exception

```
try
{
    var l = yourobject.GetMenuItemsFromLevel(ReturnMenuType.Unknown);
}
catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    //handle your exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```